# ListView working with database in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I asked a similar question before but wasn't sure how to word it. I have since looked at some tutorials and have a little more understanding of my problem. I am trying to display information from my database into a list view but can't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be great.

This is my DataBase Adapter Class:

```
public class DBAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_WORKOUTDATE = "workoutDate";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES = "notes";

private static final String TAG = "WorkoutDBAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mdb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WorkoutDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "workouts";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists workouts " +
                "(id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "title VARCHAR not null, " +
                "workoutDate date, " +
                "notes VARCHAR );";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workouts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}


public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mdb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDBHelper != null) {
        mDBHelper.close();
    }
}

//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords() {
    Cursor mCursor = mdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_WORKOUTDATE, KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

}
```

This is my AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity class:

```
public class AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends Activity {

private DBAdapter dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workouts);

    dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();



    //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
    displayListView();

}

private void displayListView() {


    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllRecords();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_WORKOUTDATE,
            DBAdapter.KEY_EXERCISE_NOTES,

    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.title,
            R.id.workoutDate,
            R.id.workoutDetails,

    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.workout_info,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    };


}
```

This is the xml file that holds the layout for where the data should go ( I think i'm not 100% sure if this is the correct way to do this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Title: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="WorkoutDate: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Workout Details"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workoutDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workoutDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workoutDetails"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/workoutDetails" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workoutDetails"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/workoutDetails" />
```

heres the workouts xml with listview1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/some_text" android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/myFilter" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/some_hint">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Heres the stacktrace. I m getting a new error message?

```
04-30 08:05:52.741 2565-2565/course.labs.todomanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: course.labs.todomanager, PID: 2565
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{course.labs.todomanager/course.labs.todomanager.AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, workoutDate, notes FROM workouts
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, workoutDate, notes FROM workouts
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
                                                                       at course.labs.todomanager.DBAdapter.getAllRecords(DBAdapter.java:91)
                                                                       at course.labs.todomanager.AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.displayListView(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.java:43)
                                                                       at course.labs.todomanager.AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.onCreate(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.java:36)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: is this code not working?

Comment: what is the problem ? application crashed? nothing display? what is size of your cursor ? .....

Comment: No this code does not work. The app crashes when i try to use it.

Comment: I am still new to this so how exactly do i get the stacktrace? thanks for trying to help

Comment: it is the error log shown in "Android Monitor" during run-time. Google "logcat" to find out more

Comment: Ok thanks i will try post it soon

Comment: I have added a stacktrace. it seems to be a problem with the id column?

Comment: yes, change `id` with `_id`

Comment: in the database adapter class?

Comment: in `DBAdapter` change create table statement and change `KEY_ROWID`

Comment: I tried that and got this error message Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, workoutDate, notes FROM workouts

Comment: did you change create table statement? if yes uninstall application and install again

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table if not exists workouts " +
                    "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "title VARCHAR not null, " +
                    "workoutDate date, " +
                    "notes VARCHAR );";                                                           This is the create table statement yes?

Comment: yes, uninstall application and run again

Comment: I tried that and got a new error,  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{course.labs.todomanager/course.labs.todomanager.AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110677/discussion-between-user3091082-and-shayan-pourvatan).

Comment: You have to define `@+id/listView1` inside of `main.xml` to fix that error

Comment: could you explain why? if its not too much trouble

Comment: You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)` and so `findViewById` will search within `main.xml` to find a view by an ID. If it cannot find that id, it will return null, thus your error.

Comment: I changed it to workout_info.xml, this is where the listview1 is but i still get an error. any idea why?

Comment: I think i have fixed my problem. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Can you please tell how you solve your problem?

Comment: I had to uninstall the app from my emulator then added data to my database again and it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong in your code, Have you tried **reinstalling** your app? So that your SQL changes will be re-validated.

*Note : My answer is base in the current EDIT and in response to the current comments.*

Answer (score 0):

In your Database creation statement change `id` column with `_id`

Comment: I tried that and got this error message  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, workoutDate, notes FROM workouts

Comment: Post your updated code of lines. What have you changed?

Comment: this is what i changed.  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id"; and this "create table if not exists workouts " +
                    "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +

Comment: I now get this error,       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference